# Could not find function "addSearchMarker"

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I recently changed my server provider. I have a shiny app and I'm using leaflet.extras

I installed the library (I've checked it twice) but in the new server appears:

```
Error: could not find function "addSearchMarker"
```

I have exactly the same shiny files in both servers. Can't figure out what's going on.

You can see it here:

New: http://casadelasestrategias.com:3838/mapadevida/

Old: http://192.95.56.146:3838/mapadevida/

PD: I've also installed the library using install.packages and devtools::install_github functions

PD2: I've tried to add leaflet.extras:::addSearchMarker but it throws "object not found"

PD3: I'm sure addSearchMarker function is from leaflet.extras (there is also same function in leafletplugins package)

PD4: I've called `library(leaflet.extras)` in ui.R and server.R

Comment: Do you have any other libraries being loaded into the server, and if so are they working correctly?

Comment: @Chabo yes! I have a lot of them and they are working correctly (even in other shiny apps)

Comment: Using the application within R studio produces no problems, correct?

Comment: @Chabo correct, it's working fine within R studio

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.

I installed `package("leaflet.extras")`, `library(leaflet.extras)`, and then called `addSeachMarker()`, and the program could not find it. After a bit of research I found the package is in fact `leafletplugins` which is not available for the current version of R, which is why when you upgraded to the new server, the package is not in use.

```
> install.packages("leafletplugins")
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘leafletplugins’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

More information here, https://github.com/asmith26/leafletplugins/blob/master/man/addSearchMarker.Rd

Edit: the older version of `leaflet.extra` (0.2) had the `addSearchMarker()` function under the `searchOSM` feature, but the newest version of `leaflet.extras` (1.0.0) does not have this feature.

Comment: But I have the function in leaflet.extras, check it here: https://ibb.co/eJFrJT 

I have not installed leafletplugins package in my computer

Comment: what version of `leaflet.extras`  do you have?

Comment: leaflet.extras 0.2 in R 3.4.4

Comment: Okay, so the newest version 1.0.0 does not have the `addSeachMarker` function in the searchOSM argument. I am guessing the server is running an updated version of the leaflet.extras package and this is why it works in R-studio with the older version, but no the new verison 1.0.0

Comment: True! I have to install it from source version 0.2!! Thank you!